# Android Application Registy

Tags: android, registry

My requirement is, First time application is installed in the Android phone, Need to get the licence code from particular shop/organization. I have created generation key using phone model number.nOW THE PROBLEM IS If its first only need to show license screen otherwise go to first screen. How we can identify the particular app is installed already or not . / from the registry ? In here registry is available.

I couldn't explore my very deeply or clearly. Sorry for that.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You may be able to use something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905240/showing-preference-screen-first-time-app-is-run-and-related-questions

Comment: That is something differ from my requirement. I have to get application installed id/ application name or something like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always set a bool value in the android.content.SharedPreferences, then in the first oncreate() check to see whether that bool value is false.

If it is push the license screen intent and perform a check for application, if its there update the preference to true. So on next start it will skip over it, where you can load your main screen.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean enteredDetails = settings.getBoolean("FirstTime", false);



if(enteredDetails){
setContentView(R.layout.main); //loads the main screen            
}
else{
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, License.class), GET_DETAILS); 
}
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to override the back button on the license view, so it quits the app, otherwise it will go back to the home page :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Context.openFileInput()` / `Context.openFileOutput()` to store a piece of information that will tell your app whether the license screen was already shown. This way you can use something like this in your main `Activity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
if (nothingWrittenInAFileCalled(FILE_NAME)) { // using Context.openFileInput()
     showLicense();
     writeAFileCalled(FILE_NAME); // using Context.openFileOutput()
}
```

If this is not satisfactory, this is also something you can check on license server side. If you send the license server a hash of the IMEI, as an example, your license server will be able to determine whether the app was already installed or not. In that case, prefer a non reversible hash: this is to avoid sending/storing the IMEI as one can see this piece of information as private data.